# Disabling swiping gestures in mobile chrome browser

Tags: android, ios, google-chrome, mobile

Mobile chrome (IOS/Android) has a feature where if you swipe at the left or right hand margins of the screen it changes tabs.

My web app uses swiping, and this "feature" just seems to get in the way.  Is there a way to disable this?

Comment: Post your code ? if you are handling the swipe your self then inside that even listener you can put     event.preventDefault(), hope this will help.

Comment: Nope, Chrome doesn't have any open APIs for that. When you swipe in the Chrome app, it's done on the very edge of the screen; maybe adjust the area your users swipe to compensate.

Comment: @RajeshCP, there is no code to post.  No event javascript event handlers seem to catch it.

Comment: @aneal, what do you mean adjust the area the users have to swipe.  As in, make the usable viewport even smaller (through padding, borders, etc.)?

Comment: are you using iScroll

Comment: I suppose. You added the ability to swipe in your web app, so I assumed you could control where the swipe occurs. If they have to swipe on the very edge in the Chrome app, have them swipe slightly before the edge or from anywhere on the page. I think the mobile version of Blogger lets you swipe between articles, look at that for an example.

Comment: @Sandy09, I am using TouchSwipe.  I was using iosSlider before that.

Comment: I checked it for https://www.google.com/maps/ somehow the gestures were not working there.

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no way to disable this gesture.

There's a ticket requesting the feature over at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=117657 if you want to star it / chime in.

Comment: To note, I spoke to the team the other day, it is very unlikely that  these gestures will removed.

Comment: It would be nice if they just moved it to like the bottom half of the screen or something so we could use the top half for app-specific functionality.

Comment: The link in Jaffa The Cake's answer points to this page. There is a bug at http://crbug/117657.

Comment: @Kinlan That's a pity - it makes Chrome on an Android pretty much unusable. What are the considerations of leaving it in? For now I'll have to stick with Firefox.

Comment: It's worth noting that the problematic gestures were changed on Chrome Mobile in Oct 2013 to only work from the toolbar, solving the OP's issue but causing an avalanche of complaints from users who liked the old gestures. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/5GLyuDs38a0%5B1-25-false%5D

Comment: opened a new one https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=459143&thanks=459143&ts=1424166333

Answer (score 0):

If you use two/multi fingers, the swipe works even from the edge/borders.