# Image processing HTML5 / Javascript (client side)

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, image-processing

I'm developping a web-app which aim to be used by mobile users, mainly iOS/Android, in order to do some image processing and send it to a server. However, my main constraint is that it must not be deployed as a native app. That's why I'll have to do this in HTML5 + Javascript and cannot delegate it to an image processing app.

I don't have any requirement for the server side implementation, at this moment, I think that Python/C++ or Golang would be nice but that's not so much important.

The basic operations that will be performed are Auto-crop + Deskew + B&W levels in order to send a "clean" image to the server.

I'm wondering what is the best way to do this. In one hand, I think that processing the image on client-side would be the best idea but I also have to rewrite all processing algorithms in Javascript. Plus, I'm a bit skeptical about the performances.

On the other hand, I'm thinking about server-side processing which can be faster but the workflow would be too heavy (mainly because of the number of interactions client-server, one for each image processing, one for sending them).

I saw this post [Client-side image processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174504/client-side-image-processing) and some people recommended `Pixlr` but I didn't found the needed functionnalities.

Does someone know a good Javascript API/Code which allows me to do what I want ? What is the "best practice" to do so ?

Thanks !

Comment: Have you considered UI/UX part of mobile web app? If you were to drag across screen in Chrome (at least iOS), for example drawing, it would make you change tab and I don't think you can override it. And I think safari would register it as go backwards/forward in history.

Comment: About the UI/UX the wanted functionnalities would be displaying images as thunmbnails, reordering it by drag'n drop and select/unselect images. To be honest, I didn't think that much about what browsers allows me to do. I think that some libraries allows me to do that and hope that the input tag `<input type="camera">`in HTML5 won't be a problem.

Comment: It is a big deal if user will get off your page while performing an action. I'm not sure about safari, but in chrome, [it can't be avoided](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478549/disabling-swiping-gestures-in-mobile-chrome-browser). The only thing you can do is avoid this actions. Or make native app, but you've said that's out of question. Btw cordova/phonegap are great choices for native apps and you can still use all your web dev skills and all the favourite libraries/frameworks.